# Java IntToBinary app: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, java.util.scanner

I have an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed" that I cant plug.

I'm nearly done with this application(written in Java). It coverts an int into binary, inverts the binary, and coverts the inverted binary into decimal. It runs, no errors, but when it terminates:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at intToBinary.AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.enterAnotherInt(AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.java:24)
at intToBinary.IntToBinary.useIntToBinary(IntToBinary.java:48)
at intToBinary.AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.enterAnotherInt(AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.java:29)
at intToBinary.IntToBinary.useIntToBinary(IntToBinary.java:48)
at intToBinary.AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.enterAnotherInt(AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.java:29)
at intToBinary.IntToBinary.useIntToBinary(IntToBinary.java:48)
at intToBinary.IntToBinary.main(IntToBinary.java:18)
```

Any suggestions, about any part of the app, are welcome.  Been doing this a little less than a year so I'm always down to learn.  But primarily, I'd like to fix the above.

Thanks.

```
 <!-- language: lang-java -->

package intToBinary;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntToBinary 
{

    private static int invertedBinaryDecimal;
    private static int _n;
    private static String binaryString;
    private static String invertedBinaryString;

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        greeting();
        useIntToBinary();
    }

    public static void greeting()
    {
        System.out.println("*Int To Binary*");
    }

    public static void useIntToBinary()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer number: ");
        while ((!in.hasNextInt())) 
        {
            System.out.print("You did not enter an integer number.  An integer number(whole
            numbers or counting numbers) is a    number like: 1, 2, 3...");
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer number: ");
            in.nextInt();
        }

        _n = in.nextInt();

        getBinary();
        getInvertedBinary();
        getIntegerComplement();

        System.out.println("You entered integer number: " + _n );
        System.out.println("In binary(base 2): " + binaryString);
        System.out.println("The inversion of this binary(base 2): " + invertedBinaryString);
        System.out.println("The inverted binary(base 2) in decimal(base 10) is: " +
        invertedBinaryDecimal);
        AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.enterAnotherInt();
    }

    public static void getBinary()
    {
        binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(_n);          
    }

    public static void getInvertedBinary()
    {
        invertedBinaryString = binaryString.replaceAll("0", "x").replaceAll("1",
        "0").replaceAll("x", "1");
    }

    public static void getIntegerComplement()
    {
        invertedBinaryDecimal = Integer.parseInt(invertedBinaryString, 2);  
    }
}
```

```js
package intToBinary;

public class AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary 
{
 private static int state;
 private static String enterYOrN;
 
  public static void enterAnotherInt() 
  {
   state = 0;
   while (state < 2) 
   {
    switch (state) 
    {
     case 0: 
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Do you want to enter another integer number? (y/n)");
      break;
       case 1:
        goodBye();
        break;
    }
              
    enterYOrN = IntToBinary.in.next();
      
    if(enterYOrN.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
    {
     state = 0;
     IntToBinary.useIntToBinary();
    }
    else if(enterYOrN.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) 
    {
     state++;
    } 
   }
  }
  
  public static void goodBye()
  {
      System.out.println("Thank you for using Int To Binary.");
      System.out.println("Good bye.");
      
      IntToBinary.in.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. One you've already identified, which is trying to read from an already closed `Scanner`. To fix it simply `return` from `enterAnotherInt()` right after your call to `AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.goodBye()` as

```
     switch (state) 
     {
        case 0: 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter another integer number? (y/n)");
            break;
        case 1:
            AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.goodBye();
            return; // instead of break;
     }
```

The second issue that you haven't realised yet is the `in.nextInt()` call within your `while` loop.

```
    while ((!in.hasNextInt())) 
    {
        System.out.print("You did not enter an integer number.  An integer number(whole numbers or counting numbers) is a    number like: 1, 2, 3...");
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer number: ");
        in.nextInt(); // use in.next() here
    }
```

To see how this fails simply enter a non-numeric input when your code prompts for an integer. You would receive an `InputMismatchException`. The reason it fails is that you're already in the loop because the input in not a number, yet your code goes ahead and fires a `nextInt()` call on the scanner which is bound to fail then.

To fix it just use `in.next()` instead of `nextInt()` there.

Comment: I just tested the while, your right, "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException".  What would be a good solution to this problem?

Comment: I've already added the solution. Perhaps, you just need to refresh the page to reflect my edits.

Comment: return after goodbye() fixed my primary issue.  However, now "Thank you for using Int To Binary." "Good bye.", displays twice in the output.  Could just make a class for closing and move goodby() to it, to solve the problem?

Comment: next() works great.  fixed the repeated printlns from goodbye().  I added state =0; after the call to goodbye() and before return.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read from a closed Scanner:

```
         switch (state) 
         {
            case 0: 
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Do you want to enter another integer number? (y/n)");
                break;
            case 1:
                AnotherOrCloseIntToBinary.goodBye(); // here you close the scanner
                break;
         }

         enterYOrN = IntToBinary.in.next(); // here you try to read from a 
                                            // closed scanner
```

The call to your `goodBye()` method should probably only be in the last line of your `main` method.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but I think case 1 with goodbye() & close(), are only reached if the user wants to exit?  State starts at 0, user input y, move to if which restarts app & returns state to 0. user input n, move to else, increment state to 1, case 1 invokes goodbye(), right?

all also say, I've moved that close() around A LOT and more or less still have the same issue.

I'll more goodBye() some more.

other ideas?